# How To Align Items To the Top In CSS/HTML Using React js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I made a navbar in react and I want it so that my list of menu options are aligned to the top. I was following a tutorial on youtube but I can't seem to find where this step was done. (youtube [Link for tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2UBjN5ER4s&t=203s&ab_channel=BrianDesign)). I tried searching and changing many things, but nothing seems to work. [Here is the picture of what I see, the top black border is where I want to align 'Home' with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/typ4O.png).

Navbar.js Code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Button } from './Button';
import './Navbar.css'
import EnderLogo from '../Logo/EnderLogo.png';

const Navbar = () => {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  const showButton = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
      setButton(false);
    } else {
      setButton(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
  }, []);

  window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);
    return (
        <>
         <nav className='navbar'>
        <div className='navbar-container'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                    TVLN <img src={EnderLogo} alt="EnderLogo" width="50" height="50" style = {{marginLeft : 5}}/>
                </Link>
                <div className = 'menu-icon' onClick = {handleClick}>
                    <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fa fa-bars'} />
                </div>
                <ul className = {click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    <li className= 'nav-item'>
                        <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            Home
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className= 'nav-item'>
                        <Link to='/gameplay' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu} style = {{verticalAlign: 'top'}}>
                            Game Play
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className= 'nav-item'>
                        <Link to='/cardpacksNFT' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            Card Packs NFT
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className= 'nav-item'>
                        <Link to='/sign-up' className='nav-links-mobile' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            Sign Up
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {button && <Button buttonStyle = 'btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>}
             </div>
         </nav>   
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Navbar.css

```
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  .navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
  
  .navbar-logo {
    color: #fff;
    justify-self: start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .fa-typo3 {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60vw;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    height: fit-content;
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-links:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  
  .fa-bars {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .NavbarItems {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .nav-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
  
    .nav-menu.active {
      background: #242222;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
    }
  
    .nav-links:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  
    .navbar-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(25%, 50%);
    }
  
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    .fa-times {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 80%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile:hover {
      background: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      transition: 250ms;
    }
  }
```

Button.css

```
:root{
    --primary: #fff;
}

.btn{
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn--primary{
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #000;
    border: 1 solid var(--primary);
}

.btn--outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--primary);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

.btn-medium{
    padding: 8px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.btn-large{
    padding: 12px 26px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.btn--large:hover,
.btn--medium:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  background: #fff;
  color: #242424;
  transition: 250ms;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to stick navbar items to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the "justify-content" property in ".nav-menu" from end to start.

```
  .nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60vw;
    justify-content: start;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
```